# Basic text mining. I am getting a UicodeencoderError

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining

```
import codecs
import csv

data = csv.reader(codecs.open("2019VAERSData.csv", "r", "latin1"))
keys = next(data)

serious_keys = list(map(lambda key: keys.index(key), ["DISABLE", "DIED", "ER_VISIT", "HOSPITAL"]))

writer = csv.writer(open("2019-vaers-serious.csv", "w"))

keys += ["SERIOUS"]
writer.writerow(keys)

for row in data:
    is_serious = False
    for key in serious_keys:
        if row[key] == "Y":
            is_serious = True
    row += ["Y" if is_serious else "N"]
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the full error

Comment: Also, if you could explain what this code does, that would be great.

Comment: Why are you using "latin1" encoding? Do you know which actual encoding your csv file using? Perhaps you should use "utf-8" instead? Or, perhaps your text data is not valid utf-8?